# jax-ws required element is missing from the XML

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm try consume a soap Web Service, but I get strange error.

first: I had a strange problem with class and interface names conflicts, to resolve that I use "-B-XautoNameResolution", So the classes were generated without problems

finish command to generated classes:

```
wsimport -keep -p <pck> -XadditionalHeaders -Xnocompile -B-XautoNameResolution <urlOfIntranetWsdl>
```

When I try call the WS i get this message:

```
ERROR (8961): A required element is missing from the XML input document.; <attributeName>
```

How can I fix that??????

whats is wrong????

wsdl(I need remove some informations because limit of characters):

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WS" xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:s0="urn:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WS">
   <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org"/>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GGG_Service" type="s0:GetInputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="GetInputMap">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="HHHH_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GGG_ServiceResponse" type="s0:GetOutputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="GetOutputMap">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Assigned_Group" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Assigned_Group_Shift_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Assigned_Support_Company" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Assigned_Support_Organization" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Assignee" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Company" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Contact_Company" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Contact_Sensitivity" nillable="true" type="s0:Contact_SensitivityType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Country" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Department" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Summary" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Notes" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="First_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Impact" nillable="true" type="s0:ImpactType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Last_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Middle_Initial" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Organization" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Phone_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Priority" nillable="true" type="s0:PriorityType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Priority_Weight" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Region" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Reported_Source" nillable="true" type="s0:Reported_SourceType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Service_Type" nillable="true" type="s0:Service_TypeType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Site" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Site_Group" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Status" type="s0:StatusType"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Status_Reason" nillable="true" type="s0:Status_ReasonType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Urgency" nillable="true" type="s0:UrgencyType"/>
     <xsd:element name="VIP" nillable="true" type="s0:VIPType"/>
     <xsd:element name="ServiceCI" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="ServiceCI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="z1D_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Contact_SensitivityType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Sensitive"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Standard"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="ImpactType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="1-Extensive/Widespread"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="2-Significant/Large"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="3-Moderate/Limited"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="4-Minor/Localized"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="PriorityType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Critical"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="High"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Medium"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Low"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Reported_SourceType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Direct Input"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Email"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="External Escalation"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Fax"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Self Service"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Systems Management"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Phone"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Voice Mail"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Walk In"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Web"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Other"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="BMC Impact Manager Event"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Service_TypeType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="User Service Restoration"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="User Service Request"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Infrastructure Restoration"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Infrastructure Event"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="StatusType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="New"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Assigned"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="In Progress"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Pending"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Resolved"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Closed"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Cancelled"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Status_ReasonType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Infrastructure Change Created"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Local Site Action Required"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Purchase Order Approval"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Registration Approval"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Supplier Delivery"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Support Contact Hold"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Third Party Vendor Action Reqd"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Client Action Required"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Infrastructure Change"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Request"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Future Enhancement"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Pending Original HHHH"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Client Hold"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Monitoring HHHH"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Customer Follow-Up Required"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Temporary Corrective Action"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="No Further Action Required"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Resolved by Original HHHH"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Automated Resolution Reported"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="No longer a Causal CI"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="UrgencyType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="1-Critical"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="2-High"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="3-Medium"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="4-Low"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="VIPType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Yes"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="No"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GGGList_Service" type="s0:GetListInputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="GetListInputMap">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Qualification" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="startRecord" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="maxLimit" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GGGList_ServiceResponse" type="s0:GetListOutputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="GetListOutputMap">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="getListValues">
      <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Assigned_Group" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Assigned_Group_Shift_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Assigned_Support_Company" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Assigned_Support_Organization" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Assignee" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Company" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Contact_Company" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Contact_Sensitivity" nillable="true" type="s0:Contact_SensitivityType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Country" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Department" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Summary" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Notes" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="First_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Impact" nillable="true" type="s0:ImpactType"/>
        <xsd:element name="HHHH_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Internet_E-mail" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Last_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Middle_Initial" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Organization" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Phone_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Priority" nillable="true" type="s0:PriorityType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Priority_Weight" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Product_Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Region" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Reported_Source" nillable="true" type="s0:Reported_SourceType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Resolution" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Service_Type" nillable="true" type="s0:Service_TypeType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Site" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Site_Group" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Status" type="s0:StatusType"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Status_Reason" nillable="true" type="s0:Status_ReasonType"/>
        <xsd:element name="Urgency" nillable="true" type="s0:UrgencyType"/>
        <xsd:element name="VIP" nillable="true" type="s0:VIPType"/>
        <xsd:element name="ServiceCI" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ServiceCI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="mmm_CI" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="z1D_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Reported_Date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Required_Resolution_Date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Target_Date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Submit_Date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Closed_Date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_Modify_Service" type="s0:SetInputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="SetInputMap">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Category_Tier3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Closure_Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Company" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Summary" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Notes" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Impact" nillable="true" type="s0:ImpactType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Product_Categorization_Tier_1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Categorization_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Model_Version" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Product_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Reported_Source" nillable="true" type="s0:Reported_SourceType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_2" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Category_Tier_3" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Resolution_Method" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Service_Type" nillable="true" type="s0:Service_TypeType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Status" type="s0:StatusType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Urgency" nillable="true" type="s0:UrgencyType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Action" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Summary" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Notes" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Type" nillable="true" type="s0:Work_Info_TypeType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Date" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Source" nillable="true" type="s0:Work_Info_SourceType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_Locked" nillable="true" type="s0:VIPType"/>
     <xsd:element name="Work_Info_View_Access" nillable="true" type="s0:Work_Info_View_AccessType"/>
     <xsd:element name="HHHH_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Status_Reason" nillable="true" type="s0:Status_ReasonType"/>
     <xsd:element name="ServiceCI" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="ServiceCI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_ReconID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="mmm_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="z1D_CI_FormName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="WorkInfoAttachment1Name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="WorkInfoAttachment1Data" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="WorkInfoAttachment1OrigSize" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Work_Info_TypeType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <!-- I need remove that because limit characters -->
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Work_Info_SourceType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Email"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Fax"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Phone"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Voice Mail"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Walk In"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Pager"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="System Assignment"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Web"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Other"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="BMC Impact Manager Event"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="Work_Info_View_AccessType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="Internal"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="Public"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_Modify_ServiceResponse" type="s0:SetOutputMap"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="SetOutputMap">
    <xsd:sequence/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GetWorkInfoList" type="s0:InputMapping4"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="InputMapping4">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Qualification" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="startRecord" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="maxLimit" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="BBBB_GetWorkInfoListResponse" type="s0:OutputMapping4"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="OutputMapping4">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="ListWOGGG" type="s0:ListWOObjectGGG"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ListWOObjectGGG">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="getListValues">
      <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoInstanceID" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoType" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoCommSource" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoSummary" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoNotes" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ParentID" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoSecureLog" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="WorkInfoSubmitDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1Data" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1OrigSize" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2Data" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2OrigSize" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3Data" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
        <xsd:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3OrigSize" type="xsd:int"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="AuthenticationInfo" type="s0:AuthenticationInfo"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="AuthenticationInfo">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="authentication" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="locale" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="timeZone" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org" xmlns="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">




          <xs:complexType name="ListGGGWorkInfo">


               <xs:sequence>


                     <xs:element ref="ListWOGGG"/>


               </xs:sequence>


         </xs:complexType>



         <xs:element name="ListWOGGG" type="ListWOObjectGGG"/>


         <xs:complexType name="ListWOObjectGGG">


               <xs:sequence>


                 <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="getListValues">


                    <xs:complexType>


                         <xs:sequence>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoInstanceID" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoStatus" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoType" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoCommSource" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoSummary" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoNotes" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="HHHHNumber" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoSecureLog" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoSubmitDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1Name" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1Data" type="xs:base64Binary"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment1OrigSize" type="xs:int"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2Name" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2Data" type="xs:base64Binary"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment2OrigSize" type="xs:int"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3Name" type="xs:string"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3Data" type="xs:base64Binary"/>


                           <xs:element name="WorkInfoAttachment3OrigSize" type="xs:int"/>


                       </xs:sequence>


                   </xs:complexType>


                 </xs:element>


           </xs:sequence>


         </xs:complexType>



    </xs:schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GGG_ServiceSoapIn">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GGG_Service" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_Modify_ServiceSoapOut">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_Modify_ServiceResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GGGList_ServiceSoapIn">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GGGList_Service" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GGGList_ServiceSoapOut">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GGGList_ServiceResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GGG_ServiceSoapOut">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GGG_ServiceResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="ARAuthenticate">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:AuthenticationInfo" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_Modify_ServiceSoapIn">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_Modify_Service" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GetWorkInfoListSoapOut">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GetWorkInfoListResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="BBBB_GetWorkInfoListSoapIn">

      <wsdl:part element="s0:BBBB_GetWorkInfoList" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSPortTypePortType">


      <wsdl:operation name="BBBB_Modify_Service">

         <wsdl:input message="s0:BBBB_Modify_ServiceSoapIn">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="s0:BBBB_Modify_ServiceSoapOut">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>


   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSPortTypeSoapBinding" type="s0:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSPortTypePortType">

      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>


      <wsdl:operation name="BBBB_Modify_Service">

         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WS/BBBB_Modify_Service" style="document"/>

         <wsdl:input>

            <soap:header message="s0:ARAuthenticate" part="parameters" use="literal">

            </soap:header>

            <soap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output>

            <soap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>


   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSService">

  <wsdl:documentation>
GGG and UUK PPP </wsdl:documentation>

      <wsdl:port binding="s0:mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSPortTypeSoapBinding" name="mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WSPortTypeSoap">

         <soap:address location="http://xxxxx-ws.yyyyy/arsys/services/ARService?server=arsapp-inti.yyyyy&amp;webService=mmm_HHHHYYYUK_WS"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Note: the same WS is call by phyton, it pass nonethis attribute and its work!!!!

Comment: Please show some code (wsdl, java classes)

Comment: now I put wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make request with post method and you missed to provide some mandatory in xml request body, so i would suggest you to read ws documentation and provide all the required field,

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation